# Investment amount at year 0

Tags: python

can I get some help on how to get in year 0 the amount of the capital without any interest.
Here is my code:

```
def futval_2():
    capital = float(input("Enter the capital you want to invest: "))
    rate = float(input("Enter the interest rate: "))
    year = int(input("For how many years you investing the money: "))

    print("\nYear     Value")
    print("-" * 16)

    for i in range(year):
        capital = capital * (1 + (rate / 100))
        print("{0:^6} £{1:<9.2f}".format(i, capital))

futval_2()
```

Output for a 10 years investment:

### Year     Value

0    £1030.00
1    £1060.90
2    £1092.73
3    £1125.51
4    £1159.27
5    £1194.05
6    £1229.87
7    £1266.77
8    £1304.77
9    £1343.92

### I'm stuck in the for loop; what I would like to see is:
Year     Value

0    £1000.00
1    £1030.00
2    £1060.90
3    £1092.73
4    £1125.51
5    £1159.27
6    £1194.05
7    £1229.87
8    £1266.77
9    £1304.77

Comment: when `i==0` you calculate the `capital` at the end of year `1`, print the value for `0` outside the loop

Comment: Or just put the calculation below, i.e. after, the `print`

Comment: @SamMason but then the value of `capital` is wrong if you want to use it for other stuff

Comment: @rioV8 but the final value isn't being used/returned, how do you know it's "wrong"?

Comment: @SamMason It is bad design to do input and output in a calculation function

Comment: About @SamMason comment did you try it? It will give the expected out you wrote. What did you mean `capital` will be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The print needs to be moved up one line so its done before the caluclation

```
def futval_2():
    capital = float(input("Enter the capital you want to invest: "))
    rate = float(input("Enter the interest rate: "))
    year = int(input("For how many years you investing the money: "))

    print("\nYear     Value")
    print("-" * 16)

    for i in range(year):
        print("{0:^6} £{1:<9.2f}".format(i, capital))   # This line was moved
        capital = capital * (1 + (rate / 100))
    

   futval_2()
```

Comment: I like to have the `capital` in my account, I will open a few accounts at your bank, it is 1 year more interest

Comment: What do you mean with capital in your account?

Answer (score 0):

Do a little index (`i`) calculation

```py
def futval_2():
    capital = float(input("Enter the capital you want to invest: "))
    rate = float(input("Enter the interest rate: "))
    year = int(input("For how many years you investing the money: "))

    print("\nYear     Value")
    print("-" * 16)

    frmt = "{0:^6} £{1:<9.2f}"
    print(frmt.format(0, capital))
    for i in range(year):
        capital = capital * (1 + (rate / 100))
        print(frmt.format(i+1, capital))

futval_2()
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, all solutions are excellent!